# Generating two normally joint distributed Random Variables

Tags: normal-distribution, random-generation, joint-distribution

If I generated two random variables with mean $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, but use the covariance matrix as the second parameter of the normal distribution - does this imply that the two variables are jointly normally distributed?

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer the question -- generated *how*?

Comment: $X$, the respective vector,  was computed in matlab using the following command: `X = (repmat(mean(r)',1,1040) + c'*z)`
Here $r$ is the matrix composed by $(r_1, r_2)$, where r_1 and r_2 are two datasets, $c$ is the lower triangular matrix yielded by the Cholesky decomposition of $\Sigma$ and $Z$ is a collection of $1040$ samples from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Comment: which is equivalent to randnormal(meanvector, covariance matrix)...

Comment: Is it correct, then, to interpret your question as asking "If I generate bivariate random Normal values with Matlab, does it imply the two variables are Normally distributed?"  If so, that raises questions about what you're actually asking. Are you concerned about the quality and characteristics of Matlab's generator? Are you asking whether the realization looks bivariate Normal? Something else?

Comment: sorry if my question is very naive, but basically it is that: two normal RV with different means and the covariance matrix as second parameter do have the normal joint density function? I think I dont get how it necessary follows that the former can be written in the form of such a density function - do you know what I mean?

Comment: The answer seems to be YES